# CKAN Error with repoze module loading

Tags: ckan

I am getting the following error when I am trying to debug an extension that I have created. I am very new to CKAN. I am trying to learn how to develop CKAN extension.

It seems like the "repoze" module is not getting loaded. Is this a python path issue? Where this module suppose to exist?

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1815, in declare_namespace
   path = sys.modules[parent].__path__
KeyError: 'repoze'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop an extension you need to have done a source install of CKAN. Assuming you've done that, you'll have put the Repoze python module into a Python virtual environment:

```
{pyenv}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/repoze
```

For Python to find Repoze etc., you need to 'activate' this environment. The [CKAN source install instructions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/install-from-source.html) describe all this, but here are the relevant bits, using the suggested environment location `/usr/lib/ckan/default`.

For a command-line program:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
```

Or for a python program run it using this executable:

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/python
```

Or for an apache deployment the environment is specified in is this part of WSGI script file:

```
activate_this = os.path.join('/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```